# Safari will not redirect to querystring URL

Tags: php, redirect, safari

I have a site built with PHP that does a redirect after certain actions are performed.

```
header("Location: http://example.com/accountArea/?v=updated");
```

I then show a message based on the value of the query string value. In safari (and only in Safari) after the redirect, you will only see a blank page. I have tried using absolute URL and relative URL in my redirect, neither work.

I was unable to find a solution by searching the web so I hope someone here is familiar with this.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in Safari's location bar? What do you see when you view source of the blank page? What happens if you go to the URL directly by typing it in to the address bar rather than being redirected? Does any error message show up in apache's `error_log`?

Comment: Also check access_log. Agreed, need more info.

Comment: Very odd. The source code actually contains the full page but the page is completely blank. Just the title is there and the destination URL is in the address bar.

Nothing in apache error log. This only happens in Safari.

Comment: hey guess what, it was my fault!
I had an open comment tag ( <!-- ) inside a block of javascript 
apparently IE and FF were ignoring it but Safari choaked. Thanks guys, problem solved.